# Centering a middle box vertically

Tags: html, css

I have 3 blocks. I would like to have the middle block (which is fixed height) to be centered vertically. So when user resize the height of the page, this box is still centered.

[image]

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/3446/

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 40px);
    background: #ff0000;
    text-align: left;
}
#center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00ff00;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
    background: #0000ff;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
      xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
  </div>
  <div id="center">
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
      zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason to `float` the left/right blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the middle box:

```
top: 50%;
position: relative;
margin-top: -50px;
```

`top: 50%` explains itself. But the problem with that is that the top of the container is centered vertically, and not the container itself. To correct that the `margin-top: -50px` is necessary, `50px` is the half heigth of the container.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/3447/

Comment: Seems to work but I noticed  one strange behaviour: when I resize the page, the middle box is not really vertically centered. But if I refresh the page (with the new page dimensions) then it is correctly centered. Any idea how to have this all time centered ?

Comment: That seems to be an issue with IE. I could fix it by using `100vh` as container-height instead of `100%`. Don't ask me why. http://jsfiddle.net/CH9K8/3450/

Answer (score 3):

You can try like this:-

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

and

```
#center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00ff00;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width: calc(50% - 40px);
    background: #ff0000;
    text-align: left;
}
#center {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00ff00;
    vertical-align: middle;
   position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
    background: #0000ff;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
      xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxx
  </div>
  <div id="center">
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
      yyyyyyyyyyyy
      <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
      zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz zzzzz zzzzzz zzzzzz
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
#center {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #00ff00;
    position:relative;
    top:calc(50% - 50px);
}
```